# Replacing $children in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm currently using vue 2 (with Nuxt).

I have 2 custom components (Form and ErrorMessage) that can be used like this:

```
<Form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="Name" autocomplete="off" v-model="name">
        <ErrorMessage v-model="name" required minlength="4"></ErrorMessage>
    <div>
</Form>
```

In `<ErrorMEssage>`, I have a `validate` method:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    validate() {
        // someLogic
    }
}
```

Inside `<Form>`, I have a `submitHandler` method that will loop through every `<ErrorMessage>` to call its `validate`:

```
<template>
  <form ref="form" @submit.prevent="submitHandler">
    <slot></slot>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    submitHandler() {
      this.$children.forEach(c => {
          c.validate()
      }) 
    }
  }
</script>
```

This works fine as $children can loop through all `<ErrorMessage>` even if they are nested deeply in multiple divs.

So my question is, how can I do the same in vue3 since $children is removed?

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 the `$children` attribute has been removed and replaced by using `$refs`

To `forEach` through a child component you need a `ref` attribute on your element and then use `this.$refs.refName.forEach` since you already have `ref=form` then `this.$refs.form.forEach` will work for your application